# How to insert/pass NULL value into Date field

Tags: soql, date, php, null

I am trying to insert a `null` value into a field of type `Date` (in SalesForce) using a PHP Script.

Here is my logic.

```
$Date = '',
$createField['Date__c'] = $Date;
```

I tried the following, but none of them work.

```
$Date = '';
$Date = null;
$Date = NULL;
$Date = 'NULL';
$Date = 'null';
```

Comment: Null should work, facing any specific errors?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `fieldsToNull` attribute, as noted in the [update](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_update.htm) documentation.

```
$createField["fieldsToNull"] = array("Date__c");
```

Comment: How do we pass the value of $Date variable into this logic? Sorry. I am little bit lost here.

Comment: @KingJava Assuming $Date is coming from somewhere else, you basically need to something like this `if(empty($Date)) { $createField.fieldsToNull = array("Date__c"); } else { $createField["Date__c"] = $Date; }`